# Passing form data between functional components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and I still try to understand how it all works.
Let's say I have got three `components`
The main `App` component where all other `components` are invoked looks like that:

```
function App() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <div>
                <Route path="/object-list" exact component={ObjectsList}/>
                <Route path="/" exact component={Header}/>
            </div>
        </Router>
    );
}
```

The Header component is that:

```
function Header() {
    return (
        <header>
            <Navigation/>
            <WebStart/>
        </header>
    )
}
```

where the `WebStart` is `form` I want to pass data from.

```
const WebStart = () => {
    const [inputName, setInputName] = useState("")
    const [inputCity, setInputCity] = useState("")
    const [selectedObjects, setSelectedObjects] = useState([])
    
    let objects = [
        {name: "Object1", city: "City1"},
        {name: "Object2", city: "City2"}
    ]
    
     const handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const objectToAdd = {inputName, inputCity};
        setSelectedObjects(objectToAdd)
    }

     return (
        <div>
            <div className="webstart-page">
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                      <input value={inputName}/>
                      <input value={inputCity}/>
                      <input type="submit"
                             value="search"
                      />
                </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

What I want to achieve is save the state with data from submitting form and then send it to `ObjectsList` component

```
const ObjectsList = ({selectedObjects}) => {
    return (
      <div>
        {
          console.log(selectedObjects)
        }
      </div>
    );
}
```

What I tried was the way you can see above. I also tried to
build `Header` component like this:

```
 function Header() {
     const [selectedObjects, setSelectedObjects] = useState([])
        return (
            <header>
                <Navigation/>
                <WebStart setSelectedObjects={setSelectedObjects}/>
                <ObjectsList selectedObjects={selectedObjects}/>
            </header>
        )
    }
```

Whatever I do I get `undefined` when try to console log `selectedObjects` in `ObjectsList` components and my ideas has just finished. I really do not know how do I need to pass this `submitted` data to other component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to share the state between components which is rendered in different routes. We can achieve this in react via [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Here is the working example [Sharing States Between Routes](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-ritchie-xj8ou?file=/src/App.js)